# Improve performance of the table pivoting in Clickhouse

Tags: pivot, clickhouse

I have a table containing the market data of 5,000 unique stocks. Each stock has 24 records a day and each record has 1,000 fields (factors). I want to pivot the table for cross-sectional analysis. You can find my script below.

I have two questions: (1) The current script is a bit complex. Is there a simpler implementation? (2) The execution takes 521 seconds. Any way to make it faster?

1.Create table

```
CREATE TABLE tb
(
    tradeTime DateTime,
    symbol String,
    factor String,
    value Float64
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(tradeTime)
ORDER BY (symbol, tradeTime)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

2.Insert test data

```
INSERT INTO tb SELECT
    tradetime,
    symbol,
    untuple(factor)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tradetime,
        symbol
    FROM
    (
        WITH toDateTime('2022-01-01 00:00:00') AS start
        SELECT arrayJoin(timeSlots(start, toUInt32((22 * 23) * 3600), 3600)) AS tradetime
    )
    ARRAY JOIN arrayMap(x -> concat('symbol', toString(x)), range(0, 5000)) AS symbol
)
ARRAY JOIN arrayMap(x -> (concat('f', toString(x)), toFloat64(x) + toFloat64(0.1)), range(0, 1000)) AS factor
```

3.Finally, send the query

```
SELECT
    tradeTime,
    
    sumIf(value, factor = 'factor1') AS factor1,
    sumIf(value, factor = 'factor2') AS factor2,
    sumIf(value, factor = 'factor3') AS factor3,
    sumIf(value, factor = 'factor4') AS factor4,
    ...// so many factors to list out
    sumIf(value, factor = 'factor1000') AS factor1000
FROM tb
GROUP BY tradeTime,symbol
ORDER BY tradeTime,symbol ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered building a materialized view to solve this with the inserts into a [SummingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/summingmergetree) ?